# 960 grid system, extending the color

Tags: css

I have two questions

1. How would i go about centering the buttons inside the grid?
2. how do i get The colors to overflow to fill the extent of the page

   ```
   <title>Virtual Harrogate!</title>
   ```

   ```
   <header class="container_12 a-new-homepage">
       <nav>
           <div>
               <ul>                                    

                           <div class="grid_12">

                               <li class="grid_2 alpha"> 
                                   <a href="" class="a-button">Login</a>
                               </li>
                               <li class="grid_2">
                                   <a href="" class="a-button">Right Now</a>
                               </li>
                               <li class="grid_2">         
                                   <a href="" class="a-button">Features</a>
                               </li>
                               <li class="grid_2"> 
                                   <a href="" class="a-button">Event</a>
                               </li>
                               <li class="grid_2">
                                   <a href="" class="a-button">About us</a>
                               </li>   
                               <li class="grid_2 omega">
                                   <a href="" class="a-button">Contact Us</a>
                               </li>                                   
                           </div>
               </ul>

           </div>
       </nav>
   </header>
   ```

and heres my layout.css, I havent altered the 960.css or text.css in any way

```
/* This is where the Format of every page and its tags are defined -- will be superceeding my styles.css */

.a-new-homepage{
    background: #2a2a2a; /* charcoal grey */
    overflow-x:visible;
    overflow-y:visible;
    bottom-border: 20px;
}

/* Header = define the h elements and the page header
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: underline;
    background-color: #78679A /* purple */
}

h2 {
}

h3 {
}

h4 {
}

h5 {
}

h6 { 
}

nav ul { /* removes all formatting from the list elements which we will go on to define */
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 

}

nav li{
    list-style-type: none;
    float: right;   
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;

}

nav li .a-button { /* sets the width and height of the class a-button locally (first number = top n bottom, second = left n right) */
    padding: 5px 15px;

}


/* buttons
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/


.a-button {
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#CCFE8B), to(#99C757));
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(100% 100% 90deg, #99C757, #CCFE8B);
    background-color:#ededed;
    -moz-border-radius:8px;
    -webkit-border-radius:8px;
    border-radius:8px;
    border:1px solid #6f9a4d;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#777777;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:15px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:10px 15px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 0px #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.a-button:hover {
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#CCFE8B), to(#99C757));
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(100% 100% 90deg, #99C757, #CCFE8B);
    background-color:#ededed;
}

.a-button:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;


/* Tabs = The the inpage tabs
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
li.a-tab  {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: center;
    display: inline-block;
    border-top:solid;
    border-right: solid;
    border-left: solid;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 15px;
    border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    border-top-right-radius: 15px;

    font-size: 16px;
    margin:0 10px; 0 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by getting the colors to overflow to fill the extent of the page?  Which colors are you talking about?  And where are they overflowing to on the page?

Anyway, to center your buttons you can take off the float:right property off your < li> tags.  Then you can change those same < li>'s to be display:inline or display:inline-block.  Then if you put a text-align:center on your  tag it will put the buttons in the middle top of your page.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough in the first place.

the charcoal grey color 2a2a2a and the purple color are currently limited to the 960 grid, i.e. they only fall within the container, i would like the colors to fill the whitespace between the container and the page edge but wondered what the CSS soloution was to this.

Followed your advice regarding the alignment issue and this appears to have done exactly what i was looking for... 

for a working example, which might make what im describing a little clearer its available at http://www.virtualharrogate.co.uk/

Comment: On that page if I go:

< header style="width:100%;text-align:center;" >

then take the float left off your <li >'s

Then make: <h1 class="container_12">a simple yet effective guide to harrogate!</h1> have width 100% instead of 960 or whatever it's set at.


Tell me if that's what you're going for otherwise you'll have to tell me what else you're looking for.

Comment: I thank you no end for your help jeschafe... That is exactly what im looking

Comment: I thank you no end for your help jeschafe... 

The code you have written is exactly the desired effect i want.

however... Im trying to work with the 960 grid system (http://www.960.gs). so in lieu of scrapping it all together im trying to find a soloution that uses the structure it provides but also goes a bit further beyond... 

Im going to try and write the code so it utilises the commands you've demonstrated and then sits the 960 system on top